Where would a telecom system design question fit on the network?
I have questions about PSTN (telecommunication) architecture as I'm working on a knowledge base for telecommunication, and I want to challenge my work and understanding of it.
I looked for Stack Exchange websites, and the only one related to network seems to be Network Engineering, which is focused on office network.
I don't know if it's something that is possible on any SE website, so I ask here.

The actual question (not up-to-date diagram, since it's not the point, it doesn't matter):
Following a training on 2G, 3G and SS7 Mobile Network Security, I write a knowledge base for myself and co-workers. I'm not a telecom expert at all, so I have a very shallow understanding of everything. That's this knowledge I try to improve.
In one slide and 30 seconds are described what a PSTN is and how it works.The showed diagram is very basic and doesn't explain a lot.
Based on information gathered on Wikipedia, other architecture diagrams found on the internet and what's explained in the training, I ended up producing this diagram:

I have high uncertainty about what I interpreted as the digital network and where SS7 and PCM are involved. Same goes for TDM. For the Network Exchange part that is not SSP, I don't know how to qualify this part.
I don't expect an answer here at all. I'm looking for the best location to ask this.

By asking what is the best site for this or where it would fit on the network, you are starting from a faulty premise.  Not all questions have a home somewhere on the Stack Exchange platform.  Some are not a fit anywhere.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info.  There is no guarantee that this question is appropriate at any Stack Exchange site.

I'm aware that this question might not have a home somewhere on Stack Exchange. It doesn't change the fact that, if there is one, I need help find it.

The only close site I can figure this might fit is on Network Engineering: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/
There are at least several dozen questions there that mention PSTN, anyway. I would check their on-topic page in their Help Center, and if you're still not sure, consider asking this same question on their Meta, instead (as I'm not sure how many of their users frequent MSE).
